# Azure Data Factory - How to handle CSV data from Microsoft graph REST source

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

I am making a pipeline of Azure Data Factory to get data from Microsoft Graph to store in Azure Data Lake through the REST API.

What I want to store is the data about [Office 365 active users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activeuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs).

The problem is this kind of data is returned under the CSV format, not the JSON one. Following the document about [copying data from REST source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest), they only accept the JSON format.

Actually I could use Batch service to handle this kind of problem but I do not appreciate this much. I have thought about changing the format of the returned data from REST source but it seems difficult. So, I would want to ask if there is any possible solution to store this kind of data without using Batch Service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact it is supported to return results in JSON format by providing `$format` query option, for example: `$format=application/json` ([details](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/reportroot-getoffice365activeuserdetail.md))

> Note: at the moment `application/json` format is **only** supported
>   under `beta` API version

Example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json
```

Comment: Thank you, you save my day. It works successfully :)

Comment: I’m running into a similar problem but it’s not graph test source. Any ideas how I can tackle this?